# SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 (SSRS) - Abonnement/Subscription: No Content/No E-Mail

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subscription, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm working on a "SQL Server Reporting Services 2008" server. I have a report which contains content every 2-7 days. I have an abonnoment, which is sending me this report every night via E-Mail. This is very annoying, when there is no content within the attached file.

Is there any way, how to don't send the subscribed Mail, when there is no content?

I found [this link](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/data-driven-subscription-in-ssrs-2008-r2.html), but I guess this is just included in SSRS2008R2, but not in SSRS2008.

Any help or ideas?
Thanks!

[image: Screenshot of the subscription, It's German, but I guess you'll understand it.]

Answer (score 1):

if you have enterprise edition, you can use data driven subscriptions. you just change the view behind the data driven subscription to not return any rows if there is no data.

if you don't have enterprise edition, you should remove the schedule in SSRS report manager (set it to run once) and then trigger the subscription using the Reportserver.dbo.AddEvent procedure. 
You call this procedure with the subscription id and it will execute this subscription. you have to write some code that determines if there is data in this report and calls the addevent procedure if there is.